# Unintended recursive call in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a table into which I have to insert data if a particular key is not present. I decided to write a stored procedure to insert data. What I want to do is:

1. Create a stored procedure.
2. Insert a bunch of rows using the stored procedure.
3. Drop the stored procedure.

I want to do all this in a single script file so that no one ever knows that the stored procedure existed.

Here is what I have:

**Create**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE My_Proc(@key varchar(10))
  AS
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[My_Table] WHERE [key] = @key)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[My_Table] (key, created, modified)
    VALUES (@key, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  END
```

**Insert**

```
EXECUTE My_Proc 99241
GO
EXECUTE My_Proc 99242
GO
EXECUTE My_Proc 99243
GO
```

**Drop**

```
DROP PROCEDURE My_Proc
```

Now I right click on my database in SQL Server Management Studio, click on `New Query` and paste the above query. I get the following output:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure My_Proc, Line 9
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure My_Proc, Line 9
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing the error. Also, When I highlight the specific `EXECUTE` command on SSMS like so `EXECUTE My_Proc 99241` the data gets inserted without any error.

Comment: Look at `MERGE` to do the whole set in one operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a GO after your Create procedure.  I believe the first "EXECUTE My_Proc 99241" is getting included as part of the procedure because of the missing GO, so basically you have a recursive call.

Create Procedure statement (as well as functions and similar statements) takes everything to the end of the batch, which is why they have to be followed by "GO" or end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of keys, some of which might be in the table, then try something like:

```
insert into my_tableC(key, created, modified)
    select key, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    from <list of keys query> k
    where k.key not in (select key from my_table)
```

If you have the list, but not in a table, you can create it as:

```
with toinsert as (
    select <keyval1> as key union all
    select <keyval2> union all
    select <keyval3> . . .
    select <keyvaln>
)
insert into my_tableC(key, created, modified)
    select key, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    from toinsert k
    where k.key not in (select key from my_table)
```

Comment: This seems like the better alternative. Thanks.

Comment: As opposed to using a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a trigger on the table you are inserting into? Because it seems that there is some  sort of looping going on with the table you are inserting into. the name of the Function/Procedure that is breaking is not the name of the procedure you created. notice the error message:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertProfessionalComponentLookupForCpt, Line 9
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertProfessionalComponentLookupForCpt, Line 9
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

Make sure there are not any triggers or Computed columns that are doing some extra work on this table.

Comment: I'm sorry. I changed the name of my procedure before posting the question, but I pasted the error for the original procedure. Will edit the error message. There are no triggers/computed columns on this table. Thanks for pointing that out.